Which query used an index in Postgresql
I'm using the pg_stat_all_indexes table to get the number of index scan used (idx_scan).
Is there a way to determine which query used an index? A sampling of the queries (like in pg_stat_statements) will be fine as well.
Thanks

No, the stats you are seeing there are cumulative. You can (a) sample the stats every N seconds and (b) log all queries then (c) compare the two but on a busy system that isn't going to be very precise.

You won't find that information in the database.
For frequent queries you could get a lead using pg_stat_statements. You could look at the execution plans of your most frequent queries and see which ones are using the index.
With indexes that are rarely used, that won't work. The only thing I could think of is drop the index and use log_min_duration_statement to see if some statement suddenly becomes slow.
